# How to include admin-ajax when loading external javascript

Tags: plugins, ajax, javascript

I'm creating a plugin that has some external Javascript and some AJAX calls ... but I don't know the best way to make reference to the `admin-ajax.php` file since the path requires some input from PHP (paths and such).

Should I declare a global javascript variable?

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is [register](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) and/or [enqueue](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) your script and then use [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to include a Javascript variable on your page. The [Codex page has this example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script):

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );
$translation_array = array( 
    'some_string' => 
    __( 'Some string to translate' ), 
    'a_value' => '10' 
);
wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $translation_array );
```

You can then access the variable with, to quote the same Codex page:

```
<script>
alert(object_name.some_string); // alerts 'Some string to translate'
</script>
```